# Installing multiple python packages at a user specific install folder

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip

Installing a list of python packages into a vurtual environment can be done by specifying install options or taeget option. This installs the specific package in user defined folder using the following commands:

```
pip install --install-option="--prefix=$PREFIX_PATH" package_name
pip install --target=d:\somewhere\other\than\the\default package_name
```

The below command helps to install multiple packages at one go using a requirements file (-r option) containing list of packages: a

```
pip install -r ./requirements.pip -e ./pyvenv
```

But this is throwing an error:

```
Local project path: './pyvenv'
Directory 'pyvenv' is not installable. File 'setup.py' not found.
Storing debug log for failure in /users/user/.pip/pip.log
```

I did not understand what the issue here, and worked it around it by first invoking the virtual python environment prompt by activating the python shell. So from my bash script I first do this:

```
source ./pyvenv/bin/activate
```

and then call the installation. This works fine for me.

```
pip install -r ./requirements.pip
```

I did not understood the error I am getting and how to fix it. Also did not find any option to specify the specific install folder along with -r option.

Answer (score 0):

In pip help, stands as follows:

```
Install Options:
  -e, --editable <path/url>   Install a project in editable mode (i.e.
                              setuptools "develop mode") from a local project
                              path or a VCS url.
```

It's seems to be that option **-e** works in different way than **virtualenv**.

Option **-e** just install a project from local path (or url), then you can work on your project locally, and import it in another project, i.e. for test purposes.